# Hide/show elements in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<tr>
<td>Name:</td>
<td><span id= "keep">Username</span><input id= "change" value= "Name" style= "display:none;"></td>  
</tr>
```

I have this, what kind of javascript do I need in order to hide the span and let the input show? This should be done by clicking this edit button:

```
<a href="#" data-original-title="Edit this user" data-toggle="tooltip" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
```

I have checked other questions on this site for duplication, but I tried alot and none answered my question!

Comment: The input is inside the span. A man can literally not hide that span and showing the input at the same time.

Comment: I never knew that there is a `type="button"` attribute available to anchor tag

Comment: Ok if I put it outside how could I make it view later? @Lain

Comment: @hiba: document.querySelector('#change').style.display = '';

Comment: Yes exactly. You cannot hide the span, as it will hide the input also. I would recommend reconsidering modifying the HTML. Otherwise, you can use remove and append javascript functionality to achieve your requirement

Comment: Ok but how could I make it show when I click on the edit button?

Comment: I have editted my question, sorry for the misunderstanding @CijoVJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function showMe(){
                document.querySelector('#change').style.display = ''; //Show the input
                document.querySelector('#keep').style.display = 'none' //Hide the span
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td>
                <span id = 'keep'>Username</span>
                <input id = 'change' value= 'Name' style= 'display:none;'>
            </td>  
        </tr>
        <a href = '#' data-original-title = 'Edit this user' data-toggle = 'tooltip' type = 'button' class='btn btn-sm btn-warning' onclick = 'showMe()'><i class = 'glyphicon glyphicon-edit'>click me</i></a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a way I could save what the edit is afterward the edit is done? For example if I refresh the page, the edit stays as they edited it?

Comment: <a data-original-title="Remove this user" data-toggle="tooltip" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-saved"></i></a>
Like if I click this save button it saves the edits?

Comment: Ehm yes, with localStorage, yet a man should create another question for that.

Answer (score 1):

Use This Simple Code

first add library

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

your html code

```
<a href="#" data-original-title="Edit this user" data-toggle="tooltip" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>edit</a>

<span id= "keep">Username</span><input id= "change" value= "Name" style= "display:none;"></span>
```

and use script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
        $(" #change").toggle();
         $("#keep").hide();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Reclicking will give weird behavior with one toggle and one static hide.